# Не могу придумать достаточно гибкую систему, чтобы при добавлении нового класса мне не пришлось переписывать остальные

Tags: c#, c++, разработка-игр

Дикий псевдокод (причем, частично на русском).

[Прочитал. С большой натяжкой соответствует](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

[А вот по этому, скорее всего, не проходит](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) (но решать модераторам). Хотя, как мне кажется, есть простое и лаконичное решение.

Допустим, у меня есть `класс КРОВЬ`, `класс КОСТИ`, `класс МЯСО` и `класс КОЖА`. В каждом из них я самозабвенно указываю, сколько и всего, и что может происходить с каждым из них. Например:

```
class КРОВЬ {
int blood; // сколько крови
КРОВЬ (int blood)
 {
  this.blood = blood;
 }
void КРОВОТЕЧЕНИЕ() { blood -= 1; }
}
```

Ну и так далее. 
Еще у меня есть `класс СПАВНЕР`, в котором имеется функция

```
SpawnObject(int posX, int posY, ..);
```

Так вот вопросы:
1) Как мне в `SpawnObject` добавить произвольное количество классов? То есть, я хочу сделать примерно так:

```
SpawnObject(100, 100, КРОВЬ, КОСТИ);
SpawnObject (150, 200, КОСТИ);
```

В идеале, эта функция должна выглядеть примерно так:

*/ЭТО ХОРОШО*

```
SpawnObject (int posX, int posY, List<Class> useClass);
```

*ЭТО ХОРОШО/*

То есть, чтобы я тупо мог при создании объекта указать произвольное число классов и в любом порядке, не создавая километры конструкторов:

*/ЭТО ПЛОХО*

```
SpawnObject(int posX, int posY, class КРОВЬ) { .. }
SpawnObject(int posX, int posY, class КРОВЬ, class КОСТИ) { .. }
```

И так далее.

*ЭТО ПЛОХО/*

2) Как все это связать в одну достаточно гибкую систему?
Допустим, я все это расписал, и теперь объект у меня умеет делать все, что нужно, все, что прописано в классах. И тут я захотел добавить ему броню:

```
класс БРОНЯ
{
void ЗАЩИТА( .. ) { .. }
}
```

И тут выясняется, что из-за того, что у объекта в функции `SpawnObject ()` добавился `класс БРОНЯ`, все начинает очень плохо работать - броня должна защищать - и она это делает, - но при этом срабатывают функции из остальных подключенных классов в полном объеме (и по факту броня не работает) - то есть получается мешанина из всех классов. Ну, надеюсь, понятно, о чем я.
Так вот, как сделать достаточно гибкую систему, в которую можно добавлять сколько угодно модулей, при этом по минимуму изменяя остальные классы? В идеале, вообще их не трогая - т.е когда я захочу создать новый класс, я должен иметь дело только с ним - вообще не трогая остальные классы.

Собственно, над этим я сейчас ломаю голову - буду рад идеям)

Comment: `public ??? SpawnObject(params Type[] anOrganTypes) { ... }` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params

Comment: Зачем вы дробите все на столь мелкие сущности - непонятно.

Comment: Если кровь, кости, мясо, кожа - это лут. То достаточно одного класса `Item` или `Loot` и всё. Всё будет создаваться из него с определенным типом, который может быть Enum. `enum LootType { Blood, Bone, Meat, Leater }` А миллион классов делать совсем не то

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов идея в том, чтобы иметь базовый класс `Object`, и расширять его "модулями" - то есть указываю, что у объекта имеется кровеносная система, кости и так далее

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не, это я так хочу сделать персонажа. Ну и вообще любой объект, просто указывая, из чего он состоит

Comment: @KremSoda то есть объект может состоять просто из мяса? или просто из крови? О_______О наверное если бы тут была задумка - можно было более адекватное что-то посоветовать. Пока это выглядит очень странно и непонятно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вот что-то типа такого хочу сделать (псевдокод):`CreateObject() { использовать класс Спрайт, использовать класс Звук,  использовать класс Зрение, использовать класс Слух, использовать класс Кровь  }` - и вот по типу этого "собрать" персонажа (ну или любой другой объект). При необходимости я просто добавлю `использовать класс Какой-то`. Ну а в самих классах уже писать, что они делают

Comment: @Abyx, начал писать на C++ с использованием GLFW

Comment: Может воспользоваться паттерном декоратор?

Comment: Возможно, вам пригодится это: https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

Comment: Когда ты разработчик 1С но хочешь писать игры =)

Answer (score 3):

Каждый из ваших классов, насколько я понимаю, каким-то образом изменяет характеристики обладателя. При этом, в идеале, ни класс персонажа не должен знать ничего о деталях реализации каждого из классов-модификаторов, ни эти классы ничего не должны знать друг о друге.

Выделяем интерфейс `IModifier`:

```
public interface IModifier
{
    void Apply(ICharacter hero);
}
```

Классы-модификаторы реализуют этот интерфейс каждый по-своему:

```
public class Armor : IModifier
{
    public int Might { get; protected set; }

    public Armor()
    {
         // Могут быть какие-нибудь SuperArmor, PoorArmor, так что 
         // Armor можно сделать абстрактным, унаследовав от него остальные
         Might = 2;
    }

    public void Apply(ICharacter hero)
    {
        hero.Defence *= Might;
    }
}

public class AidKit : IModifier
{
    public int HealPoints {get; protected set; }

    public AidKit()
    {
        HealPoints = 20;
    }

    public void Apply(ICharacter hero)
    {
        hero.Health += HealPoints;
    }
}
```

И т.п.

При создании класса персонажа к нему применяется набор модификаторов:

```
public HeroFactory : ICharacterFactory
{
    public ICharacter Create(IEnumerable<IModifier> modifiers)
    {
        var hero = new Hero(); /* Разные типы персонажей можно создавать
        разными фабриками или внедрять через IoC-контайнер, но это за рамками
        рассматриваемого вопроса*/
        foreach (var mod in modifiers)
        {
            mod.Apply(hero);
        }
        return hero;
    }
}
```

Так, в принципе, можно реализовать не только "состав" персонажа, но и воздействие от разного типа оружия. Только тогда в интерфейсе следует объявить пару методов `ApplyToOwner` и `ApplyToOther`. Например, какой-нибудь вундер-меч может давать +20 к защите и наносить повреждения на -10 врагам, против которых он применен...

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал ознакомится с остальными паттернами кроме фабрики, визитером и командой в частности, так же понадобится машина состояний, обзервер (наблюдатель) и куча других=) Да и основное что я вижу у парня проблема с DI  контейнером

Answer (score 2):

Но в том месте где вы захотите поработать с КОСТЯМИ-СОПЛЯМИ, вам надо знать что это за классы.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <vector>

struct A {};
struct B { void print() {std::cout << "    I'm b method\n";} };
struct C {};

struct Object
{
    std::vector<boost::any> parts;

    void DoSomethingWithB() 
    {
        std::cout << "Object::DoSmethingWithB addr " << (void*)this << "\n";
        for (auto& p : parts) 
        {
            if (B * b = boost::any_cast<B>(&p)) 
            {
                b->print();
            }
        }
    }
};

Object SpawnObject(int, int, const std::vector<boost::any>& parts) 
{
    Object obj;
    obj.parts = parts;
    return obj;
}

int main()
{
    SpawnObject(0, 0, { A(), B(), C() }).DoSomethingWithB();
    SpawnObject(0, 0, { A(), C(), C() }).DoSomethingWithB();
}
```

Вывод:

```
Object::DoSmethingWithB addr 0x7ffd476cdc60
    I'm b method
Object::DoSmethingWithB addr 0x7ffd476cdc60
```